# ConcurrentHashMap removal of keys

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to figure out how to write a thread-safe, expiring entries, cache. This cache will be used as a `no-hits` cache, so that if an entry is not found in some storage, I will put it in this cache and avoid the subsequent calls in the next minutes.

There will be multiple threads reading and writing this cache.

There will be just a single ThreadSafeCache instance in my application.

I'm not sure if removing an entry in the contains method will arise synchronization issues.

How may I test this class for thread-safety?

Kind regards

```
public class ThreadSafeCache 
{
    private final Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();
    private final Duration expiration = Duration.ofMinutes(10);
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<CacheKey, CacheValue> internalMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public boolean contains(String a, String b, byte[] c, String d)
    {
        CacheKey key = new CacheKey(a, b, c, d);
        CacheValue value = internalMap.get(key);

        if (value == null || value.isExpired())
        {
            internalMap.remove(key);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void put(String a, String b, byte[] c, String d)
    {
        internalMap.computeIfAbsent(new CacheKey(a, b, c, d), key -> new CacheValue());
    }


    private class CacheValue
    {
        private final Instant insertionDate;

        private CacheValue()
        {
            this.insertionDate = clock.instant();
        }

        boolean isExpired()
        {
            return Duration.between(insertionDate, 
 clock.instant()).compareTo(expiration) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure of what you are building exactly but, just in case, did you consider using Google's Guava? It seems to match what you are trying to build. Take a look at the following link:
[https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache)

Comment: I'm not using a Guava Cache because I don't know what to put as value, it is actually null. I'm trying to avoid expensive IO op to get that null, so when that expensive IO returns null, I just want to record it, and avoid that null in the next minutes.

Comment: Use a surrogate, like `Boolean.TRUE`. Then use Guava/Caffeine with `expireAfterWrite(duration)` for equivalent behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling 2 Map operations in the same function, meaning there is scope for interleaving (i.e. another operation happens in between the 2 operations in the function, changing its behaviour). To fix this, you can put the map operations in a `synchronized (internalMap) {}` block. Note, you must do this to any method that interacts with the map in 2 discrete method calls.

From a code-style point of view, it is bad practice to modify the map in the `contains` method. This will make your code less predictable. Another person coming to your code for the first time (or you in a few months time) may not remember that `contains()` actually **modifies** the cache. `contains` implies that it simply checks the cache, rather than modifying it.

My recommendation would be:

- If the key has expired, simply return false.
- In the `get()` method, check if the value has expired, and, if it has, compute a new one there.

Comment: I agree with the naming part, but I can't agree when it comes to the concurrency part. In the `contains()` OP is performing two operations on the map that depend on each other in non-synchronized method. I don't think that's thread-safe.

Comment: I totally missed that. Time for bed perhaps, thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question: "I'm not sure if removing an entry in the contains method will arise synchronization issues".

=> No problem with remove operation because you use synchronized collections ConcurrentHashMap, it's the best choice.

extra: another way to get a synchronized collections is: Collections.synchonize(myCollection), but it's not OK if we use remove operation in multithread envi (maybe in a loop), it throws ModificationException.

So, use synchronized collections (ex: ConcurrentHashMap) is alaways recommended

Comment: In the `contains()` OP is performing two operations on the map that depend on each other in non-synchronized method. Performing two thread-safe methods depending on each other isn't guaranteed to be thread-safe